Find the max ID value from records in the same table from a group of records that are non-zero in another field
I have a series of bird species names that are sorted taxonomically (by ID). I would like to cluster sub-species (which currently have a clust value of 0) with the species (clust <> 0) that falls above them in the table.
Here is a subset of the data and below is the desired query output to update the clust with newclust
Table Data



ID
Clust
code




2
2
ostric2


3
0
comost1


4
0
comost2


5
0
comost3


6
0
comost4


7
3
ostric3


8
0
y00934


10
4
grerhe1


11
0
grerhe2


12
0
grerhe3


13
0
grerhe4


14
0
grerhe5


15
0
grerhe6


16
5
lesrhe2


17
6
lesrhe4


18
0
lesrhe1


19
0
lesrhe5


20
7
lesrhe3



I'd like to fill in the 0 values in clust with the number (ID of the species) directly above them in the table.
Desired query output



ID
Clust
code
NewClust




2
2
ostric2
2


3
0
comost1
2


4
0
comost2
2


5
0
comost3
2


6
0
comost4
2


7
3
ostric3
3


8
0
y00934
3


10
4
grerhe1
4


11
0
grerhe2
4


12
0
grerhe3
4


13
0
grerhe4
4


14
0
grerhe5
4


15
0
grerhe6
4


16
5
lesrhe2
5


17
6
lesrhe4
6


18
0
lesrhe1
6


19
0
lesrhe5
6


20
7
lesrhe3
7



I tried a left join thinking that it would give me access to all of the records in the a table to find that record where a.id is < b.id and a.clust is non-zero.
select b.id, b.clust, b.code, (select max(a.id) where a.clust<>0 and a.id<b.id)   
    from db as a 
    left join db as b on a.id=b.id;

The query gives me a null value for Newclust whether I use max or not. I suspect it is due to forcing a.id=b.id. I can see how to do this with a procedure-oriented programming language but would like to use a mysql query.
Thanks

Use the Custom variables:
SELECT
ID,
Clust,
CODE,
case when Clust != 0 then @pre := Clust ELSE @pre END AS NewClust
FROM test,(SELECT @pre := NULL) tmp
ORDER BY ID


Usually such tasks are solved using window functions. Take a look at the topic "gaps and islands".
When using self-join, as in your example, you need to calculate the join condition.
See example
select t.*,coalesce(b.Clust,t.Clust) as newClust
from(
select a.*
  ,(select max(a2.id) from data a2 where a2.clust<>0 and a2.id<a.id) prevId
from data as a 
  )t
left join data as b on b.id=t.prevId

OR, same
select a.*,coalesce(b.Clust,a.Clust) as newClust
from data as a 
left join data as b 
  on b.id=(select max(a2.id) from data a2 where a2.clust<>0 and a2.id<a.id)




ID
Clust
code
prevId
newClust




2
2
ostric2
null
2


3
0
comost1
2
2


4
0
comost2
2
2


5
0
comost3
2
2


6
0
comost4
2
2


7
3
ostric3
2
2


8
0
y00934
7
3


10
4
grerhe1
7
3


11
0
grerhe2
10
4


12
0
grerhe3
10
4


13
0
grerhe4
10
4


14
0
grerhe5
10
4


15
0
grerhe6
10
4


16
5
lesrhe2
10
4


17
6
lesrhe4
16
5


18
0
lesrhe1
17
6


19
0
lesrhe5
17
6


20
7
lesrhe3
17
6



fiddle
With window funtions and method "gaps and islands", every row with Cust<>0 is first row of group - gap. Running sum of "first row of group" (gap number) is number of group.
Then we calculate new Clust as max(Clust) within group (partition by ...).
select *
  ,max(Clust)over(partition by clustGroup)newClust
from(
select *
  ,sum(case when Clust<>0 then 1 else 0 end)over(order by id)clustGroup
from data
)t




ID
Clust
code
clustGroup
newClust




2
2
ostric2
1
2


3
0
comost1
1
2


4
0
comost2
1
2


5
0
comost3
1
2


6
0
comost4
1
2


7
3
ostric3
2
3


8
0
y00934
2
3


10
4
grerhe1
3
4


11
0
grerhe2
3
4


12
0
grerhe3
3
4


13
0
grerhe4
3
4


14
0
grerhe5
3
4


15
0
grerhe6
3
4


16
5
lesrhe2
4
5


17
6
lesrhe4
5
6


18
0
lesrhe1
5
6


19
0
lesrhe5
5
6


20
7
lesrhe3
6
7



fiddle
